# Замена div внутри другого div, JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть div .the_content. Внутри него есть еще div .kc__wrap. **Задача - заменить содержимое kc__wrap в the_content на пустоту.** Есть код:

```
Doc = Jsoup.connect(contentUrl).get();
                imagesRec = doc.select("div.post-featured-img amp-img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrcUrl = imagesRec.attr("abs:src");

                Elements p = doc.select("div.the_content");
                Elements d = doc.select("div.kc__wrap");
                contentNearly = p.text();
                contentNearlyD = d.text();
                contentFinal = contentNearly.replace(contentNearlyD, "").trim();
cntContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(contentFinal));
```

Здесь все хорошо, вместо .kc__wrap подставляется пустота. Но мне нужно, чтобы текст в итоге выводился в html со всей правильной разметкой, а не просто как текст. Нижеприведенный код не работает:

```
Doc = Jsoup.connect(contentUrl).get();
                imagesRec = doc.select("div.post-featured-img amp-img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrcUrl = imagesRec.attr("abs:src");

                Elements p = doc.select("div.the_content");
                Elements d = doc.select("div.kc__wrap");
                contentNearly = p.html();
                contentNearlyD = d.html();
                contentFinal = contentNearly.replace(contentNearlyD, "").trim();
cntContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(contentFinal));
```

Может кто подсказать, как вывести получившийся текст в формат html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Рабочий код:

```
doc.select("div.kc__wrap").remove();
Elements p = doc.select("div.the_content");
contentFinal = p.html();
cntContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(contentFinal));
```

Достаточно было удалить div при помощи remove()  и уже потом просто вывести оставшийся текст в TextView.